# Doctrine - How can I set a default value for a column in a relationship?

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony4

I read the documentation [here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/annotations-reference.html)  to set default values on a `@Column` but I'm trying to do the following:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="smallint", options={"default" : 0})
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="OrderStatus")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="status", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $status;
```

It just seems like the `@Column` overwrites that `@ManyToOne` relationship as when I make a migration there are no foreign keys created, yet if I remove the `@Column` there are. How can I keep the relationship yet also specify a default value?

Comment: Yes, I saw that - doesn't have anything about default value in a relationship

Comment: I am perplexed when I see a legitimate, well-formed question like this with an unexplained downvote. Who's that helping?

Comment: To ponder on your actual question: is it possible to define a default value on a foreign key, this seems like something to investigate at the database engine level itself? I guess a question I would have is what is the significance of `0` - could you use `null` instead? AFAIK the relationship is nullable as you define it there.

Comment: I suppose I could set null to be the same as 0 in the lookup table, but for the sake of knowing how this works lets say that it needs to be 0.  And thank you for the help with the downvote - I never understand those either.

Comment: In other words, if you need to differentiate a record that does not have an `OrderStatus` with a value, then `null` should be perfectly fine. Otherwise, if you need to set a default `OrderStatus` then I would consider setting this at the ORM level - either by assigning a default `OrderStatus` at object creation in your constructor or manually at a later stage.

Comment: OK. yes for now I wound up just setting it at a later stage however I have concerns about if someone ever changes that code it's not forced on a database level.  To me it seems like if Column can do it, why shouldn't JoinColumn be able to.

Comment: For the sake of knowing how this works - I am really not sure if it does at the ORM level. If you were trying to do this at the SQL level, then it seems possible - as long as the default value refers to an id that exists in the associated table.

Comment: To answer your last comment - I guess the constraint is literally that - a foreign key relationship would have to exist under normal circumstances (obviously this can depend on the db engine). This is different to a regular column where there is no association to consider.

Comment: ok thank you for the help :)

Comment: My pleasure :) I learned some interesting things myself.